# issue when using scala filter function in rdd

Tags: scala

I started learning scala and Apache spark. I have an input file as below without the header.

```
0,name1,33,385 - first record

1,name2,26,221 - second record

unique-id, name, age, friends
```

1) when trying to filter age which is not 26, the below code is not working.

```
def parseLine(x : String) =
  {
    val line = x.split(",").filter(x => x._2 != "26")

  }
```

I also tried like below. both cases it is printing all the values including 26

```
val friends = line(2).filter(x => x != "26")
```

2)when trying with index x._3, it is saying index outbound.

```
val line = x.split(",").filter(x => x._3 != "221")
```

Why index 3 is having an issue here?

Please find below the complete sample code.

```
package learning

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._

object Test1 {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit =
  {

   val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Test1")
   val lines = sc.textFile("D:\\SparkScala\\abcd.csv")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val testres = lines.map(parseLine)
    testres.take(10).foreach(println)


  }
  def parseLine(x : String) =
  {
    val line = x.split(",").filter(x => x._2 != "33")
    //val line = x.split(",").filter(x => x._3 != "307")
    val age = line(1)
    val friends = line(3).filter(x => x != "307")
    (age,friends)

  }


}
```

how to filter with age or friends in simple way here.
why index 3 is not working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to filter on the array representing a single line and not on the RDD that contains all the lines.
A possible version could be the following (I also created a case class to hold the data coming from the CSV):

```
package learning

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._

object Test2 {

  // A structured representation of a CSV line
  case class Person(id: String, name: String, age: Int, friends: Int)

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {

   val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Test1")
   Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

   sc.textFile("D:\\SparkScala\\abcd.csv") // RDD[String]
     .map(line => parse(line)) // RDD[Person]
     .filter(person => person.age != 26) // filter out people of 26 years old
     .take(10) // collect 10 people from the RDD
     .foreach(println)

  }

  def parse(x : String): Person = {
    // Split the CSV string by comma into an array of strings
    val line = x.split(",")

    // After extracting the fields from the CSV string, create an instance of Person
    Person(id = line(0), name = line(1), age = line(2).toInt, friends = line(3).toInt)
  }
}
```

Another possibility would be to use `flatMap()` and `Option[]` values instead. In this case you can operate on a single line directly, for instance:

```
package learning

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._

object Test3 {

  // A structured representation of a CSV line
  case class Person(id: String, name: String, age: Int, friends: Int)

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {

   val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Test1")
   Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

   sc.textFile("D:\\SparkScala\\abcd.csv") // RDD[String]
     .flatMap(line => parse(line)) // RDD[Person] -- you don't need to filter anymore, the flatMap does it for you now
     .take(10) // collect 10 people from the RDD
     .foreach(println)

  }

  def parse(x : String): Option[Person] = {
    // Split the CSV string by comma into an array of strings
    val line = x.split(",")

    // After extracting the fields from the CSV string, create an instance of Person only if it's not 26
    line(2) match {
      case "26" => None
      case _ => Some(Person(id = line(0), name = line(1), age = line(2).toInt, friends = line(3).toInt))
    } 
  }
}
```